# How can I delete an account on a specific site?

Tags: support, profile-page, user-accounts

My account has 20 (!) sites associated to it.  I only use it for 3-5 sites.  To reduce clutter, I would like to delete my profiles that I do not use much.

I have went through [the delete-account procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleting-account), but when I enter the profile URL as:

```
http://russian.stackexchange.com/users/5772/alex
```

it gives the error message:

> oops! this isn't a link to a valid profile

What procedure do I go through to delete my profile only on certain sites?

Comment: You need to go to each site individually. Your profile link only works on the site that profile belongs to. You can't enter any profile link on every site.

Comment: Thank you, that seems to have worked.

Comment: @Gnat Good catch: one I missed when posting.  However, in that case the OP didn't post or vote, so he could simply use the "Delete Account" button in the profile.  But the answer there would apply in my case.